# Inner Join of 3 Tables

Tags: sql

In Table Approver:

```
No Userid 
1   3
2   7
```

In Table Users:

```
No UserID RoleID
1  3        1
2  4        1
3  5        2
4  7        3
```

Table Roles

```
RoleID Name
1      ABC
2      BCD
3      CDE
```

I want to select rolename of users in table approver like:

```
Userid Name
3      ABC
7      CDE
```

Comment: What did you tried so far and what was the problem with the your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why approver.no is on the user and approver table.... I'm going to assume userId is unique in both situation..... if thats the case this should work:

```
select 
    u.userid, 
    r.name
from
    Approver as a
    inner join [Users] as u on a.userId = u.UserId
    inner join [Roles] as r on u.roleId = r.roleId
```

if that is NOT the case and you need the approver.no user.UserId combo to be unique than the following should work:

```
select 
    u.userid, 
    r.name
from
    Approver as a
    inner join [Users] as u on a.userId = u.UserId
    and a.No = u.No
    inner join [Roles] as r on u.roleId = r.roleId
```

the differences between these two as far as the result set concerns can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0daa9/4

Notice that the second query returns a single result against the provided data

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  a.Userid,
  r.Name
from 
  Approver a
  join Users u on a.no = u.no
  join Roles r on u.RoleID = r.RoleID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.UserID,
       Name
FROM   Approver A
       JOIN Users U
           ON A.UserId = U.UserId
       JOIN Roles R
           ON R.RoleId = U.RoleId
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1347a/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Approver.UserId, Name from Approver INNER JOIN Users
 on Approver.No=Users.No
    INNER JOIN Roles
 on Users.RoleID=Roles.RoleID
```